# Atom, Structure-View installation problem

Tags: atom-editor

i'm new here, and need some help for fix this problem with installing Structure-View on Atom. I tried to install it with cmd and with install package, but it give me the same error... i can't understand what it say me...

```
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated lodash.isarray@4.0.0: This package is deprecated. Use Array.isArray.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/ramitos/tern-jsx.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\carlo\.atom\.apm\_logs\2020-09-08T10_33_19_647Z-debug.log
```

if is helpfull i can share the full log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I have installed Git